# LOGGER::info is not consumed as s -> LOGGER.info(s)

Tags: java, logging, lambda, java-stream, method-reference

I have defined a logger instance as follows:

```
private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName());
```

I have an array of strings that I want to log, so I used the following:

```
Arrays.stream(new String[]{"ABC", "DEF", "XYZ"}).forEach(LOGGER::info);
```

However, nothing is printed into the log. But, if I change the reference method to an equivalent lambda form, it prints into the log:

```
Arrays.stream(new String[]{"ABC", "DEF", "XYZ"}).forEach(s -> LOGGER.info(s));
```

What am I missing here?

I tried the following approaches as well and they all behave the same:

```
Stream.of("ABC", "DEF", "XYZ").forEach(LOGGER::info);
List.of("ABC", "DEF", "XYZ").forEach(LOGGER::info);
```

Even Intellij IDE highlights `s -> LOGGER.info(s)` with yellow and suggests changing it to `LOGGER::info`.

---

I tried to define a custom class:

```
static class Consumer
{
    void consume(String s)
    {
        LOGGER.info(s);
    }
}
```

and use it in place of `LOGGER::info`:

```
Consumer consumer = new Consumer();
Arrays.stream(new String[]{"ABC", "DEF", "XYZ"}).forEach(consumer::consume);
```

It prints into the log!

---

The `Logger` class has two overloaded methods:

```
void info(String msg)
```

and

```
void info(Supplier<String> msgSupplier)
```

but only the first is assignable to `void forEach(Consumer<? super T> action)`, I believe.

Comment: Interesting... it's working for me well. What version of java did you use?

Comment: I tried it on both Java 8 and Java 11. Currently, I am using Oracle JDK 11.0.1.

Comment: Works for me on java 8u191

Comment: `Arrays.stream(new String[] { "ABC", "DEF", "XYZ" }).forEach(LOGGER::info);` works fine for me (Java 8), LOGGER being a `java.util.logging.Logger`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider that code:

```
Arrays.stream(new String[]{"ABC"}).forEach(LOGGER::info);
Arrays.stream(new String[]{"ABC"}).forEach(s -> LOGGER.info(s));
```

The difference is in the first case source of message is:

```
java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator
```

in the second:

```
Main
```

Probably your logger has some filter that does not let logging events from `java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator` class.

Try to check result of `LOGGER.getFilter()`

Comment: You got it right. I have a filter that prevents any logging other than from my own packages. Thanks.

Comment: @Eng.Fouad glad to help!